# Relation between multiples of recurrences

Tags: recurrence-relations

If I have a recurrence

$$R_n = aR_{n-1}+bR_{n-2}, R_1 = x, R_2 = y$$

and now I want to consider this new recurrence

$$Q_n = c(aQ_{n-1}+bQ_{n-2})$$

Is there any way to relate the two (perhaps by setting some specific initial values of $Q$)?

Comment: I don't see an easy connection between the two sequences. If you choose for example $Q_2=R_2$ and $Q_1=R_1$ you get $Q_3=cR_3$ but $Q_4=c(acR_3+bQ_2)$ which is not $c^2 R_4$ because $Q_2=R_2 \neq c R_2$.

Comment: Look at the roots of the corresponding characteristic polynomials. I don't think they are easily related.